# Remove inline style from string element using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

Suppose I have this string:

```
let string = '<h1 style="lots of class"> </h1><h2> <p style="bunch of class"> </p> <p style="bunch of class"> </p></h2>';
```

so basically it is a bunch of elements like this but in string:

```
<h1 style="bunch of class"> </h1>
<h2> 
  <p style="bunch of class"> </p>
  <p style="bunch of class"> </p>
</h2>
```

using jquery or vanilla javascript, how do I remove the style attribute from the string?

I have already tried this one:

```
$(string).find('h1').removeAttr('style');
```

but it is not working

Comment: Do you need to remove all the styles or `h1` style only?

Comment: @KoshVery all styles for all elements. Basically what I really want is the vanilla version of all elements without any attributes or styles just pure skeleton.

Comment: I've updated my answer to help you strip any attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to remove all the styles from the string, you might do it like this:

```js
let string = '<h1 style="color: red;">H1 Foo</h1><h2 style="color: yellow;">H2 Foo<p style="color: green;">P Foo</p><p style="color: blue;">P Foo</p></h2>';

$('<div>' + string + '</div>')
  .find('[style]').attr('style', null)
  .appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**
In order to give you what you really wanted, I wrote the following jQuery extension.
It strips all attributes from html fragment, except those you want to keep.
Can be applied to jQuery object.
Takes an array of attrs to keep (optional).
Returns html string like jQuery `html()` method does.

```js
$.fn.extend({
  stripHTML: function(keep = []) {        
    return $('<div>')
      .append(this)
      .find('*').each(function(i, e) {
        for (var {name} of [...e.attributes]) {
          if (!keep.includes(name)) e.removeAttribute(name);
        }
      })
      .end()
      .html();
  }
});

let string = '<h1 Title="h1" style="color: red;">H1 Foo</h1><h2 style="color: yellow;">H2 Foo<p style="color: green;">P Foo</p><p style="color: blue;" >P <a href="foo">Foo</a></p></h2>';

let keep = ['href', 'name', 'value']; // attrs to keep

let stripped = $(string).stripHTML(keep);

$('body').html(stripped);

console.log(stripped);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is the answer I have accepted because this is what I exactly needed; to remove all of the styles on all of elements and it's child elements. But in case other people will come across this problem, @Rory McCrossan 's answer works well however you have to filter all other child element from it's parent.

Comment: @Daniel if you want to use this logic, I'd strongly suggest avoiding the `*` selector as it's needlessly slow. Use `[style]` instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, great improvement! Thank you, I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's two potential issues here. Firstly, you need to create a jQuery object from `string` and save a reference to it. If you don't do that you'll lose the changes you made to the HTML.

Secondly you need to use `filter()` instead of `find()`, as there is no single root level 
node to search from in the HTML string. Try this:

```js
let string = '<h1 style="color: red;">H1 Foo</h1><h2 style="color: yellow;">H2 Foo<p style="color: green;">P Foo</p><p style="color: blue;">P Foo</p></h2>';

let $string = $(string);
$string.filter('h1').removeAttr('style');
$('body').append($string);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i liked the _secondly_. Didn't aware to filter such way.

Comment: Your answer is awesome I am almost getting there. Just to add another question how do I remove the style for the p elements inside the h2 as well?

I have tried doing

$string.filter('h2 p').removeAttr('style');

but didn't work

Comment: You need to `filter()` to get the `h2`, then `find()` the `p` within it: `$string.filter('h2').find('p').removeAttr('style');`

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is, create a virtual element in the code and place the content in it. then find the element and remove the attribute:

```js
let str = '<h1 style="lots of class">h1</h1><h2> <p style="bunch of class"> h2 > p</p> <p style="bunch of class"> h2 > p </p></h2>';

let $div = $('<div>')
$div.html(str).find('h1').removeAttr('style');

$(document.body).append($div.html())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can achieve this through regex.

```
const string = '<h1 style="lots of class"> </h1><h2> <p style="bunch of class"> </p> <p style="bunch of class"> </p></h2>';
const stringNoStyle = string.replace(/style="(.*?)" /g, '')
// <h1> </h1>
// <h2>
//    <p> </p>
//    <p> </p>
// </h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `div` and insert string to `innerHTML` of it. Then select `h1` and remove `style` from it.

```js
var string = '<h1 style="color:red">h1</h1><h2 style="color:red">h2</h2>';
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = string;
div.querySelector("h1").removeAttribute("style");
document.body.append(div)
```